# Inventory integration

Tags: inventory, integration, custom-product-type

Anyone knows how to get the custom type from the product editing page? (Need to get via code into phtml file)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These are the custom attributes and you can easily get these attributes value from the product object.

**For Example:**

To achieve this, you can load the product by product id.

```
protected $_productRepository;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
}
```

and here is the method to load the product:

```
$product = $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
```

Here is the way to get the custom type:

```
$product->getCustomType();
```

You can do the same code to the PHTML block class function and call that function into the PHTML file like:

```
$customType = $block->functionName();
```